# Reducing difference between two graphs by optimizing more than one variable in MATLAB/Python?

Tags: python, matlab, optimization, curve-fitting, levenberg-marquardt

Suppose 'h' is a function of x,y,z and t and it gives us a graph line (t,h) (simulated). At the same time we also have observed graph (observed values of h against t). How can I reduce the difference between observed (t,h) and simulated (t,h) graph by optimizing values of x,y and z? I want to change the simulated graph so that it imitates closer and closer to the observed graph in MATLAB/Python. In literature I have read that people have done same thing by Lavenberg-marquardt algorithm but don't know how to do it?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "graph" of your function? I find your question very unclear.

Comment: @AndrasDeak By graph I mean we plot values of h against t for both simulated and observed.The formula for function 'h'  also has x,y,z variables in it which we want to optimize such that simulated becomes (as close as possible) similar  to observed. I modified my question. May be it helps you to understand question.

Comment: If if use `lsqcurvefit` function of MATLAB what will be my 'x' and 'xdata'. I could understand 'ydata' will be the values of 'h' for observed data but I am unable to differentiate between 'x' and 'xdata' of `lsqcurvefit` function, if I have to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually trying to fit the parameters `x,y,z` of the parametrized function `h(x,y,z;t)`.

### MATLAB

You're right that in MATLAB you should either use [`lsqcurvefit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqcurvefit.html) of the Optimization toolbox, or [`fit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fit.html) of the Curve Fitting Toolbox (I prefer the latter).

Looking at the documentation of `lsqcurvefit`:

```
x = lsqcurvefit(fun,x0,xdata,ydata);
```

It says in the documentation that you have a model `F(x,xdata)` with coefficients `x` and sample points `xdata`, and a set of measured values `ydata`. The function returns the least-squares parameter set `x`, with which your function is closest to the measured values.

Fitting algorithms usually need starting points, some implementations can choose randomly, in case of `lsqcurvefit` this is what `x0` is for. If you have

```
h = @(x,y,z,t) ... %// actual function here
t_meas = ... %// actual measured times here
h_meas = ... %// actual measured data here
```

then in the conventions of `lsqcurvefit`,

```
fun   <--> @(params,t) h(params(1),params(2),params(3),t)
x0    <--> starting guess for [x,y,z]: [x0,y0,z0]
xdata <--> t_meas
ydata <--> h_meas
```

Your function `h(x,y,z,t)` should be vectorized in `t`, such that for vector input in `t` the return value is the same size as `t`. Then the call to `lsqcurvefit` will give you the optimal set of parameters:

```
x = lsqcurvefit(@(params,t) h(params(1),params(2),params(3),t),[x0,y0,z0],t_meas,h_meas);
h_fit = h(x(1),x(2),x(3),t_meas);  %// best guess from curve fitting
```

---

### Python

In python, you'd have to use the `scipy.optimize` module, and something like [`scipy.optimize.curve_fit`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) in particular. With the above conventions you need something along the lines of this:

```
import scipy.optimize as opt

popt,pcov = opt.curve_fit(lambda t,x,y,z: h(x,y,z,t), t_meas, y_meas, p0=[x0,y0,z0])
```

Note that the `p0` starting array is optional, but all parameters will be set to 1 if it's missing. The result you need is the `popt` array, containing the optimal values for `[x,y,z]`:

```
x,y,z = popt
h_fit = h(x,y,z,t_meas)
```

Comment: I defined a separate function file named 'h' as `function [output] = h(para,t); x=para(1); y=para(2); z=para(3); output = _formula with x,y,z & t_; output; end` and then I created another  file where I created `observed` and `t` vectors having same length as that of 'output' and a vector `initial = [1 2 3]`. Then I used lsqcurvefit as `newpara=lsqcurvefit(@h,initial, t,observed)` but by running it MATLAB says 'error using `h` for not having enough input arguments'.

Comment: I had to define `t` inside 'h' file of function even though I defined it in other file where I called `lsqcurvefit` along with giving sample/observed data for `h` and t is also in input arguments of function of file `h`. This I could not understand that why I have to define `t` explicitly in file 'h' when I am giving it as input argument.

Comment: @AtherCheema I cannot reproduce your problem. By using an anonymous function, this won't produce an error: `initial=[1 2 3]; t=1:10; observed=-2*t; h=@(para,t) para(1)*t+para(2)*(-t)+para(3)*t.^2;  newpara=lsqcurvefit(h,initial, t,observed)`. If you use a named function instead, you should indeed use `@h` in the call to `lsqcurvefit`, otherwise it should work the same way. Is your function name not being confused with some other function/variable in the workspace? This is a really short (and bad) name for a function...

Comment: @ AndrasDeak  Thank you very much. I am just wondering what is difference between using `lsqcurvefit` and `fminbnd` with rmse to be used as the function to be reduced? `lsqcurvefit` also reduces sum of square of errors between sample data calculated data.  I tried both and they gave very different optimized values with same degree of fitting.

Comment: @AtherCheema did you really do the exact same thing with them? Same tolerance levels, same starting points? Anyway, they could still be using different algorithms under the hood, so for problems with multiple possible solutions you might get wildly different results. Otherwise I'm not intimately familiar with these functions, but it sounds reasonable that they both can be used to perform curve fitting (but I'd use the one that has "curvefit" in its name).

Comment: @ AndrasDeak  As `fminbnd` does not require initial guess so its results are different but you are right `fminsearch` and `lsqcurvefit` with same initial values are giving same optimized values. Moreover I am getting some error using `fit` function for same problem [here](http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/273589-getting-error-using-fittype-line-356).

Comment: It's quite possible that user-defined functions can't be passed as strings. Use an anonymous function instead, [like this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fittype.html#btpaend-18).

Comment: Actually I was unable to write this whole function as user defined. `function ydata = ytest(x,k,S);
  g_vecrow = (xlsread('signal1.xlsx','signal','C2:C999'))';g_vec = g_vecrow-g_vecrow(1) ;
t_vec = x.*5; dist = 45; b = 2;  
for i = 2:998;
    t = t_vec(i);
    g = g_vec(i);
tow = 0:5:t-1;
wt(i) = ((1/k*b/S)^(1/2)* dist)/(2 * sqrt(pi))* trapz(tow,g.*(t - tow).^(-3/2).*exp(-dist^2./(4*k*b/S*(t - tow))));   
end
ydata = wt + 147.9;
end ` g_vecrow is data of 998 points. If you could help me in writing above function as anonymous function.

Comment: You can leave that named function as it is:) Just call `fittype` as `fittype(@ytest,...)`.

Comment: Made following changes to script  `ft = fittype(@ytest,x,k,S);
[f,output] = fit( x, ydata, ft, 'StartPoint', [0, 1,] );` and got following error `Undefined function or variable 'k'` where `k` is the variable that I want to optimize along with `S`.

Comment: You should've looked at the link I gave you 2 comments above... Have you tried just `ft=fittype(@ytest)`?

Comment: Thank you very much for inquiring back. To be honest, I did not understand what u mean by `ft=fittype(@ytest)` because by using `ft=fittype@(ytest); [f,output] = fit( x, ydata, ft, 'StartPoint', [0, 1,] )` the error is `First input argument must be a string, cell array or anonymous function` so I thought may be I am so witless to understand your point. I did my work with `lsqcurvefit` then.

Comment: @AtherCheema it turns out that `fittype` is defined in a very stupid way. If I'm not mistaken, `fittype(@(x,k,S) ytest(x,k,S))` should not throw an error. But I admit I'm not certain in anything by now:)